# How to convert csv to json in python?

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm very new to programming, have been learning python from past 3/4 weeks and
this is one of the assignments given.

Input

```
A, B, C, D
1, 2, 3, 4
5, 6, 7, 8
```

Output

```
{{A:"1", B:"2", C:"3", D:"4"}, {A:"5", B:"6", C:"7", D:"8"}}
```

I've been trying with the code as:

```
import csv
import json

csvfile = open('test.csv','r')
jsonfile = open('test.json','w')

x = ("a","b","c","d")

reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, x)
for row in reader:
    json.dump(row, jsonfile)
```

The output for this code comes as below:

```
{"a": "1", "null": ["5", "6", "7", "8", "9"], "c": "3", "b": "2", "d": "4"}
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Input is not csv. Output is not valid json. Do you mean list of dictionary? `[{A:”1”, B:”2”, C:”3”, D:”4”}, {A:”5”, B:”6”, C:”7”, D:”8”}]`

Comment: i'm sorry..!!yes it's list of dictonary

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Dump after processing whole rows.

---

```
import csv
import json

with open('test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    rows = list(reader)

with open('test.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(rows, f)
```

Comment: i just tried that but it didn't work.
output is as below 

[{"A,B,C,D": "1,2,3,4"}, {"A,B,C,D": "5,6,7,8"}, {}, {}]

Comment: @naren, I tested before post this. It created a file `test.json` with `[{"A": "1", "C": "3", "B": "2", "D": "4"}, {"A": "5", "C": "7", "B": "6", "D": "8"}]` as a content.

Comment: got it, thanq very much @falsetru , trust your guidence will make me excel in python

Comment: @naren, Your input file mismatch with the input in the question.

Comment: actually i was trying to modify the inputs and check , i forgot to select the correct input file. anyways thanq @falsetru

Comment: @falsetru aren't you reinventing the [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe, Thank you for pointing that out. I updated the answer to use `DictReader`.

Comment: Excellent ! and without the headers as a first line ... you GOT IT !

Answer (score 4):

For those who like one-liners:

```
import csv
import json

json_data = [json.dumps(d) for d in csv.DictReader(open('file.csv'))]
```

Checkout this fiddle for a working example: 
https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/5992b8f4-552f-4970-91b6-a52cdee16ebc/?i=true

Comment: This approach makes my **numeric value(int, float)** of each key to **string**. Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import json

# Constants to make everything easier
CSV_PATH = './csv.csv'
JSON_PATH = './json'

# Reads the file the same way that you did
csv_file = csv.DictReader(open(CSV_PATH, 'r'))

# Created a list and adds the rows to the list
json_list = []
for row in csv_file:
    json_list.append(row)

# Writes the json output to the file
file(JSON_PATH, 'w').write(json.dumps(json_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert CSV to Json Python

```
import csv
import urllib2

url = '<YOURCSVURL>'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
cr = csv.reader(response)

line = {}
data = []

for index, row in enumerate(cr):
    if index:
        for index, col in enumerate(row):
            line[name[index]] = col

        data.append(line.copy())
    else:
        name = row

print data
```

Answer (score -3):

You can attempt it using this code :

```
def inputfunction(lists):
 tmpdict = {}
 for element_index in range(len(lists)):
     tmpdict[headers[elementindex]] = lists[element_index]
 return tmpdict

def run(filename):
 filelist = [eachline.split(',') for eachline in open(inputfile,'r')]
 headers = filelist[0]
 values = filelist[1:]
 finallist = []
 for lists in values:
     finallist.append(inputfunction(lists))
 return finallist
```

Comment: The code in your answer isn't indented properly. Also, the `return` you have in that `for` loop at the end of the `run()` function will only allow the loop to execute one iteration.

Comment: 1: Not properly indented.  2: You are just creating a dictionary of every list which is not a JSON format.3: You have to pass "headers" also an argument in your 'input function" 4: In the run function you have to change "filename "parameter to "inputfile" or vice-versa.