# tkinter optionmenu looking up excel list

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an optionmenu working ok looking from a list in the code but what if the list is to be maintained externally in an excel file. How would I go about looking up an excel file, say called....vehicles.xlsx and the list would be in column A? Would I use pandas or there is ther an existing option within python
The working code is below but obviously I want to get rid of the list and replace it with an excel lookup.

Sorry in advance if there is a tutorial somewhere but I can't seem to find it and I'm pretty new to python.

Thanks

self.cars=["car1","car2"]
self.installin = tk.OptionMenu(self,self.var,*self.cars).grid(row=4,column=2,sticky=tk.W, padx=8, pady=8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking out my Excel 2003, seems you can save spreadsheets as `xml`, `txt`, `csv` among others.

Not sure how the text file would look, but I'd start with that as it might save you a library import ([xml](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)), in case that's a consideration.

Edit: In case it isn't, check out csvs'  [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader), I believe it's the quickest solution.

If you like/prefer to work with json, you can also convert csv to json with a [few lines of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170071/csv-to-json-convertion-with-python).

Edit 2: Extracting the first column from a csv file may look like this:

```
import csv

with open('install.csv') as csvfile:

    # Generating a DictReader object
    reader=csv.DictReader(csvfile)

    # This will contain the values in the 1st column
    first_col=[]

    # Assuming the first column is titled 'Ins' and skipping empty cells
    first_col.extend([row['Ins'] for row in reader if row['Ins']])
```

Alternatively, if you didn't name the columns, you can just use `csv.reader`. The relevant part then looks like this:

```
reader=csv.reader(csvfile)  # instead of csv.DictReader(csvfile)

first_col=[]

first_col.extend([row[0] for row in reader if len(row) and row[0]])
```

Comment: Sorry, new to this,don't understand it yet. I've added the following                                                                                                       with open('install.csv') as csvfile:
       self.reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for row in self.reader:
               read(row['Ins'])                                                                                                    self.installin = tk.OptionMenu(self,self.var,*self.reader) I know its wrong, the example in the tutorial shows how to print but that's not what I need, is there a read function?

Comment: sorry for delay, didn't have a chance to try it out but I still can't get this to work. How would I apply this to the optionmenu tkinter object?

Comment: What we did is get a list of the items in the first column of a csv file. In your case, just use self.cars instead of first_col, and continue as you did before.