# Translating from CSV to JSON

Tags: python, json, csv, dictionary

I wish to translate some data from CSV to Json.

The way i am doing it now, is by deleting the headings and re writing them all out again in JSON as an appendix.

Is there are quicker/better/more efficent way to do this, then to rewrite all my code again:

Below is my current code:

```
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        dataReader = csv.reader(f)
        next(dataReader)
        data = {filename:[]}
        for row in dataReader:
            data[filename].append({"ACTIVITY DATE": row[0], "OWNER ID": row[1], "OWNER NAME": row[2], "FACILITY ID": row[3], "FACILITY NAME": row[4], "RECORD ID": row[5], "PROGRAM NAME": row[6], "PROGRAM STATUS ": row[7], "PROGRAM ELEMENT": row[8], "PE DESCRIPTION": row[9], "FACILITY ADDRESS": row[10], "FACILITY CITY": row[11], "FACILITY STATE": row[12], "FACILITY ZIP": row[13], "SERVICE CODE": row[14], "SERVICE DESCRIPTION": row[15], "SCORE": row[16], "GRADE": row[17] })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert csv to json in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170071/how-to-convert-csv-to-json-in-python)

Comment: Does the CSV file have a header line? Does it matter in which order the columns are exported? `DictReader` will give you named columns, but if you want a specific order, you have to enumerate them anyway. A loop over the enumeration will probably be tighter, still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, don't discard the header:

```
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(reader)
    data = {
        filename:[
            dict(zip(header, row)) for row in reader
        ]
    }
```

Alternatively, and more straight-forwardly, you can use a DictReader instead of a regular reader:

```
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    data = {filename: list(reader)}
```