# Is there any function in python or can we create it in which we can give input (string) and in return output (dictionary)?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, django

I am using OCR to read invoice from pdf and able to extract them in string format.
now i want to store in Json format in Database.

below is input in which i am able to extract key and value by:

```
keys_=["None" if x == '' else x for x in unclean_data[2].lower().split(',')]
print(keys_)
key_: ['units ', 'item code ', 'description ', 'unit price (inc-gst) ', 'discount % ', 'total (inc-gst) ', 'None']

values_=["None" if x == '' else x for x in unclean_data[3].lower().split(',')]
print(values_)
value_: ['31.68 ', 'vhc ', 'amstel blanco 60x120 ', '$39.60 ', 'None', '$1', '254.53 ', 'None']
```

now using res_two = dict(zip(key_,values_) i am able to convert it, but i want to search key using regular expression in input and replace it with the keys show in the output.

example `**enter code here**`
"Item_Code","Description","Quantity","Unit_price_ex_GST","Value_ex_GST","GST","Discount%","Total(Inc_GST)"

```
Input = Table: Table_1
Units ,Item Code ,Description ,Unit Price (inc-GST) ,Discount % ,Total (inc-GST) ,
31.68 ,VHC ,Amstel Blanco 60x120 ,$39.60 ,,$1,254.53 ,
1 ,D0001 ,Delivery Charge ,$145.00 ,,$145.00 ,
    
Expected Output = {
 "Item_Code":"VHC",
 "Description":"Amstel Blanco 60x120",
 "Quantity":3,
 "Unit_price_ex_GST":$39.60 ,
 "Value_ex_GST":40.91,
 "GST":'',
 "Discount%":'',
 "Total(Inc_GST)":$1,254.53 },
```

Comment: In simpler words do you want to turn a csv file into json?

Comment: Yes that will also works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert csv to json in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170071/how-to-convert-csv-to-json-in-python)

Comment: Not exactly but it might helps a lot.
the JSon from OCR is way too much complicated for me.

Comment: import csv
import json

csvfile = open('file.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('file.json', 'w')

fieldnames = ("FirstName","LastName","IDNumber","Message")
reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile, fieldnames)
out = json.dumps( [ row for row in reader ] )
jsonfile.write(out)

This helps me thanks a lot for direction @AbdulAzizBarkat